# Move X and Y starting point on a moving object in any angle

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm working on a game with HTML5 Canvas and JavaScript. It's a simple space shooting game with a cannon in the center of the screen. I can rotate the cannon and fire missiles in the same angle as the cannons direction.

But I have a problem. For the missiles X and Y starting point, I'm using the X and Y position of the cannon. This looks weird, because I want the missile to start outside of the cannon, like perhaps 50 pixels in the direction of the angle. How do I calculate that?

With this code I create Missile objects:

```
var dX = Math.cos(this.playerRotationAngle * Math.PI / 180); 
var dY = Math.sin(this.playerRotationAngle * Math.PI / 180); 
this.activeMissilesArray.push(new Missile(cannon.posX, cannon.posY, dX, dY));
```

And this is from the constructor function of the Missile object where I calculate the direction:

```
this.directionX = dX * this.speed;
this.directionY = dY * this.speed;
```

The Draw method:

```
Draw: function(context)
{
    context.drawImage(this.missile, this.posX-20, this.posY-20);
}
```

The Update method:

```
    Update: function()
{
    this.posX += this.directionX;
    this.posY += this.directionY;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using your speed formula with a value of 50 to adjust the initial position?

```
// inside the Missile constructor
// instead of:
//   this.posX = x;
//   this.posY = y;
// do:
this.posX = x + 50 * dX;
this.posY = y + 50 * dY;
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! This works perfect! I just tried this.posX = x + 50 without the * dX, but with * dX it's working just like I want it!